# Need help to change this c# code to Vb

Tags: c#, vb.net

```
public void ChangeList(IEnumerable<LineInfo> newLineList)
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        BeginInvoke((Action<MainForm, IEnumerable<LineInfo>>)((t, e1) => t.ChangeList(e1)), this, newLineList);
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Public Sub ChangeList(ByVal newLineList As IEnumerable(Of LineInfo))    
    If InvokeRequired Then        
        BeginInvoke( DirectCast( (Sub(t, e1) t.ChangeList(e1)), (Action(Of MainForm, IEnumerable(Of LineInfo)) ) ), Me, newLineList)
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

I did this without a compiler handy, so there may be a miss-placed parentheses in that BeginInvoke call somewhere, but otherwise it should be right.

The Telerik converter that others are using is missing the generic type on the newLineList argument and tries to use a Function lambda (which expects a return value) rather than a Sub lambda (which does not need a return value).

Answer (score 1):

according to the [Telerik code converter](http://converter.telerik.com/) it is:

```
Public Sub ChangeList(newLineList As IEnumerable(Of LineInfo))
    If InvokeRequired Then
        BeginInvoke(DirectCast(Function(t, e1) t.ChangeList(e1), Action(Of MainForm, IEnumerable(Of LineInfo))), Me, newLineList)
        Return
    End If    
End Sub
```

[That is not the only converter available](https://www.google.co.uk/search?&q=c%23+to+vb+converter), there is [another one here](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/)

**EDIT**

you can get around the compiler warning like by changing it to a function:

```
Public Function ChangeList(newLineList As IEnumerable(Of LineInfo))
    If InvokeRequired Then
        BeginInvoke(DirectCast(Function(t, e1) t.ChangeList(e1), Action(Of MainForm, IEnumerable(Of LineInfo))), Me, newLineList)        
    End If
End Function
```

I now get a warning that it doesn't return a value on all paths and that you might get a null reference exception if you try and use the result.  As long as you don't you should be ok.

you can remove the warning by explicitly returning nothing:

```
Public Function ChangeList(newLineList As IEnumerable(Of LineInfo))
    If InvokeRequired Then
        BeginInvoke(DirectCast(Function(t, e1) t.ChangeList(e1), Action(Of MainForm, IEnumerable(Of LineInfo))), Me, newLineList)        
    End If
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

This is untested though, but may help you

Comment: i have tried this but not working ,error: t.ChangeList(e1) "expression does not produce a value"

Comment: @suneehs I have posted an update which you can try.

Comment: Thanks Sam, the error is around function calling " t.ChangeList(e1) " ,it shows "expression does not produce a value".ie.the "t" does not contain a function ChangeList(),i think it is not cast the MainForm.In c # "t" is shows as "(parameter) MainForm t" but not in vb

Comment: @suneehs is the function ChangeList declared in MainForm?  That was how I set it up when I was testing it and it seemed ok for me...

Comment: have worked by changing the Functin to Sub

Comment: and you have changed the ChangeList to be a function rather than a Sub as in the update?  Perhaps you could paste the full code of the form which does not compile?

Comment: here is the code..Public Sub ChangeList(newLineList As IEnumerable(Of LineInfo))
     If InvokeRequired Then 
    Dim action As Action(Of MainForm, IEnumerable(Of LineInfo)) = Sub(t, e1) t.ChangeList(e1) BeginInvoke(action, Me, newineList) 
    Return 
    End If 
    End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the c# to vb converters online? [c# to VB converter](http://converter.telerik.com/)

```
Public Sub ChangeList(newLineList As IEnumerable)
If InvokeRequired Then

    BeginInvoke(DirectCast(Function(t, e1) t.ChangeList(e1), Action(Of MainForm, IEnumerable(Of LineInfo))), Me, newLineList)
    Return
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: i have tried this but not working ,error: t.ChangeList(e1) "expression does not produce a value"

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Sub ChangeList(newLineList As IEnumerable)
    If InvokeRequired Then

        BeginInvoke(DirectCast(Function(t, e1) t.ChangeList(e1), Action(Of MainForm, IEnumerable(Of LineInfo))), Me, newLineList)
        Return
    End If

End Sub
```

you might want to edit your question and also use this 
http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

Comment: i have tried this but not working ,error: t.ChangeList(e1) "expression does not produce a value"